# Error with UWP application in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#

In my current UWP application, I am receiving 19062 errors, all of which begin with "The .winmd file (filename) contains type (type name) outside its root namespace (namespace name)." Examples of the full error code are shown below.

I have attempted the following to resolve the error:

- Restarting Visual Studio
- Rebuilding the Solution
- Reinstalling the most recent version of the Windows SDK
- Restarting my computer

The project was building fine a few days ago. Since then, I have not done anything to my computer which would result in such an issue with my solution.

Here are the error code examples:

> "The .winmd file 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd' contains type 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.ISearchQueryLinguisticDetails' outside its root namespace 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract'. Make sure that all public types appear under a common root namespace that matches the output file name."
>
> "The .winmd file 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd' contains type 'Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation'. The use of the Windows namespace is reserved."
>
> "The .winmd file 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd' contains type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation.IValuePatternIdentifiers' outside its root namespace 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract'. Make sure that all public types appear under a common root namespace that matches the output file name."

I am relatively new to UWP, and am failing to interpret the error. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help.

Jordan.

Comment: Have you cleaned the project?

Comment: No I did not. That fixed it. As aforementioned, I am relatively new to this. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project needed to be cleaned to avoid these errors. OP confirmed in comments that it was a cause.